# Sink JSON into SQL Server database using ADFv2 copy data task with stored procedure

Tags: json, sql-server, azure-data-factory

I'm trying to retrieve JSON from a REST API and store it directly in a Azure SQL database using the Data Copy task. However I can't get the stored procedure to work since the "Table Type" and "Table Type Parameter" doesn't seem to "support" JSON as input.

My stored procedure looks like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[InsertNewCustomers]
    @JSONObject NVARCHAR(MAX)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    INSERT INTO [tmp].[Customer] ([customerNumber], [name])
        SELECT [customerNumber], [name]
        FROM OPENJSON(@JSONObject, '$.collection')
             WITH (
                    [customerNumber] [NVARCHAR](250) '$.customerNumber',
                    [name] [NVARCHAR](250) '$.name'
                  )
END
```

Now, using that stored procedure needs a table type which seems to only support a SQL Server table type and not JSON... or how ?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the example at : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-azure-sql-database#invoke-a-stored-procedure-from-a-sql-sink

```
--In your database, define the table type with the same name as sqlWriterTableType.
---The schema of the table type is the same as the schema returned by your input data.

CREATE TYPE [dbo].[JSONObjectType] AS TABLE(
    JSONObject NVARCHAR(MAX) NOT NULL
);
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[InsertNewCustomers]
    @JSONTable [dbo].[JSONObjectType] READONLY
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    --INSERT INTO [tmp].[Customer] ([customerNumber], [name]) --..testing
        SELECT [customerNumber], [name]
        FROM @JSONTable AS t
        CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(t.JSONObject, '$.collection')
             WITH (
                    [customerNumber] [NVARCHAR](250) '$.customerNumber',
                    [name] [NVARCHAR](250) '$.name'
                  )
END
GO
```

--test

```
DECLARE @input AS [dbo].[JSONObjectType];

INSERT INTO @input(JSONObject) 
VALUES(N'{"collection" : {"customerNumber" : "A", "name" : "Smith"}'), (N'{"collection" : {"customerNumber" : "B", "name" : "Jones"}');

EXEC [dbo].[InsertNewCustomers] @JSONTable = @input;
```

Comment: Hello @Iptr, I tested your solution and it works in Sql Server. But when I try to run it in Azure Data Factory. I get the following error: 

Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'JSONObject', table '@JSONTable'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails. The data for table-valued parameter "@JSONTable" doesn't conform to the table type of the parameter. SQL Server error is: 515, state: 2 The statement has been terminated.,Source=.Net SqlClient Data

I have defined Table type: JSONObjectType and Table type parameter name: JsonTable. Any help there?